# Replace string with array content in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

```
String = "Test string Test"
array = ["link1","link2"]
```

How can replace string like this ?

Output should be `String = "link1 string link2"`

Comment: String is a Ruby standard class name, and local variable should be in lowercase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String#gsub! could return an enumerator, so this is easy:

```
string.gsub!("Test").each_with_index { |v, i| array[i] }
```

Comment: you had written it with `gsub` earlier, why did u replace it with `gsub!`? It is always good to avoid `gsub!` as it modifies the original object.

Comment: I did that because from the question I thought krunal wanted the original string to be modified.