# How can I create a method to replace words in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the following code:

```
<% (params.keys & User::FILTERS).each do |f| %>
  <%= f %>
<% end %>
```

results in

> country gender_type photos_count

I want to create a method like:

```
def rename 
 country = Country of Origin 
 gender_type = Gender 
 photos_count = Number of Photos
end
```

that can used in the above code that will substitute the strings.

Comment: Perhaps any of these already asked questions could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021835/replace-string-with-array-content-in-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502165/how-to-replace-text-in-a-ruby-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.

One way would be to declare a `Hash` in your controller that looks like this:

```
@sub_words = {
  "country" => "Country of Origin",
  "gender_type" => "Gender",
  "photos_count" => "Number of Photos"
}
```

And then in your view do:

```
<% (params.keys & User::FILTERS).each do |f| %>
  <%= @sub_words.fetch(f, f) %>
<% end %>
```

You could also use a method as you suggested. In your controller or helper do:

```
def rename(filter)
  case filter
  when "country"
    "Country of Origin"
  when "gender_type"
    "Gender"
  when "photos_count"
    "Number of Photos"
  else
    filter
  end
end
helper_method :rename
```

In your view:

```
<% (params.keys & User::FILTERS).each do |f| %>
  <%= rename(f) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting the following errors `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'sub_words' for #<#<Class:0x007fb5e8366c30>:0x007fb61b338f28>):`   and `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'rename' for #<<Class:0x007ff104324888>:0x007ff13c76b7d8>):`

Comment: sorry, updated my answer. You'll prob need to prepend `@` to the variable name and/or declare your `rename` method as a [`helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method).

Comment: it is being passed as `"country":String`